# Confusion with point class and driver class in java

Tags: java, class, point

Basically I had to write a Point class and then a driver class for it, this is done in eclipse as well. The problem I am having is that when I try and call the "pointX and pointY" variables to change the value of the point in the driver class, I keep getting an error. In my instructions the variables had to be declared as private in the PointClass, but then it makes a problem when trying to call them in the PointTest class. Also I'm confused on if my pointers/get & set methods in the PointClass are correctly written.

**To clarify on what my requirements were, this is a summary of my instructions:**

1. Write a Point class. The Point class should be written as an abstract data type.
2. Include the following instance variables:

   a. an integer representing the x coordinate

   b. an integer representing the y coordinate

   c. The instance variables in your program should only be directly accessible inside of the Point class.
3. Have 2 constructors for the Point class.

   a. a no-arguments constructor, set both of the instance variables to 10 (ten).

   b. a constructor having two arguments, one for each of the two instance variables, set the instance variables to those argument values.
4. Include get and set methods for each of the two instance variables identified in step 2.
5. Include a toString method in your Point class.
6. Write a client program called PointTest
7. In the PointTest class do the following

   - Create an object of type Point using the no-arguments constructor.
     Call this point1

     Create a second object of type Point using the two-argument
     constructor. Call this point2. Use the values of x = 11, y = 24

     Display point 1 instance variables after a call to
     point1.toString()

     Display point 2 instance variables after a call to
     point2.toString()

     Change the x value of point1 to 35 using the set method for the x
     value of point1

     Display point 1 instance variables after a call to
     point1.toString()

     Display point 2 instance variables after a call to
     point2.toString()

     Change the y value of point2 to 13 using the set method for the y
     value of point2

     Display point 1 instance variables after a call to
     point1.toString()

     Display point 2 instance variables after a call to
     point2.toString()

**The code for the Point class is as follows**

```
    public class PointClass {

    private int pointX;     //set instance variables
    private int pointY;


    public void setPoints() {       //method to set the points values
        pointX = 10;
        pointY = 10;

    }

    public void getPoints(int x, int y){    //method to set arguments to instance variables 
        pointX = x;
        pointY = y;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int getPointX() {
        return pointX;
    }

    public void setPointX(int x) {
        this.pointX = x;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int getPointY() {
        return pointY;
    }

    public void setPointY(int y) {
        this.pointY = y;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String toString(){   //toString method to display the values
        return "x = " + pointX + "y = " + pointY;
    }

}
```

**The code for the driver is as follows**

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class PointTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        PointClass p = new PointClass();


        System.out.print("Lab1 Point");
        System.out.print("January 16, 2014");

        Point point1 = new Point();             //set point1 as no argument 
        Point point2 = new Point(11,24);       // set point2 as argument with x and y

        System.out.print(point1.toString());  //display point1 from toString method
        System.out.print(point2.toString()); //display point2 from toString method

        point1 = pointX(35);

        System.out.print(point1.toString());  
        System.out.print(point2.toString()); 

        point2.pointY(13);

        System.out.print(point1.toString());  
        System.out.print(point2.toString()); 
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Okay after correcting some stuff, I'm still a bit confused since I'm still getting one error, is this how everything is supposed to be?

```
public class PointClass {

private int pointX;     //set instance variables
private int pointY;


public void setPoints() {       //method to set the points values
    pointX = 10;
    pointY = 10;

}

public PointClass(int x, int y){    //method to set arguments to instance variables 
    this.pointX = x;
    this.pointY = y;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

public int getPointX() {
    return pointX;
}

public void setPointX(int x) {
    this.pointX = x;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

public int getPointY() {
    return pointY;
}

public void setPointY(int y) {
    this.pointY = y;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

public String toString(){                       //toString method to display the values
    return "x = " + pointX + "y = " + pointY;
}

}
```

public class PointTest{

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    System.out.print("Lab1 Point");
    System.out.print("January 16, 2014");

    PointClass point1 = new PointClass();         //set point1 as no argument 
    PointClass point2 = new PointClass(11, 24);  // set point2 as argument with x and y

    System.out.print(point1);  //display point1 from toString method
    System.out.print(point2); //display point2 from toString method

    point1.setPointX(35);

    System.out.print(point1);  
    System.out.print(point2); 

    point2.setPointY(13);

    System.out.print(point1);  
    System.out.print(point2); 
}

}
```

Comment: There is no `abstract` `Point` class in code you provided. Also in your `PointTest` class you are using/including `java.awt.Point` which has nothing to do with your `PointClass`.

Comment: @Pshemo good catch! besides `getPoints(int x, int y)` you use this method to  set something, should not call `setPoints(..)` ..Also you don't need to call `System.out.print(point1.toString());` just `System.out.print(point1);` is fine! `toString` will be called automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a member variable is `private` you cannot directly access it outside of it's own class like you have tried here

```
point2.pointY(13);
```

You must use the `public` setters/getters you wrote to accomplish this.

```
point2.setPointY(13);
```

Also, in your `PointClass` you have a method `getPoints(int x, int y)` which is actually SETTING the variables. The method name should be changed to `setPoints(int x, int y)`.

Also, you have overridden the `toString()` method of your `PointClass`. Because of this you do not have to explicitly call `toString()`.

```
System.out.println(point1.toString()); // Unneeded
System.out.println(point1);  //Better
```

**Edit**

Once you have removed `import java.awt.point;` you will need to add a constructor to your `PointClass`.

```
public class PointClass {

private int pointX;     //set instance variables
private int pointY;

//
//This is your new constructor
//
public PointClass(int x, int y) {
    this.pointX = x;
    this.pointY = y;
}
```

Now you can create instances of this class like this

```
Point point1 = new Point(11, 24); // Old way - Incorrect
PointClass point1 = new PointClass(11, 24) // Better - This will make objects of your class.
```

**Edit #2**

Here's the final classes I wrote for you:

**PointClass**

```
public class PointClass {

    //Set instance variables
    private int pointX;
    private int pointY;

    //Default Constructor - Starts at (0, 0)
    public PointClass() {
        this.pointX = 0;
        this.pointY = 0;
    }

    //Constructor with specified values
    public PointClass(int x, int y){
        this.pointX = x;
        this.pointY = y;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setPointX(int x) { 
        this.pointX = x; 
    }
    public void setPointY(int y) {
        this.pointY = y;
    }

    //Getters
    public int getPointX() { 
        return this.pointX;
    }
    public int getPointY() {
        return this.pointY;
    }

    //toString for use with System.out.println()
    public String toString() {
        return "x = " + this.pointX + " y = " + this.pointY;
    }
}
```

**PointTest**

```
public class PointTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Lab1 Point");
        System.out.println("January 17, 2014");
        System.out.println();

        PointClass point1 = new PointClass();         //set point1 as no argument 
        PointClass point2 = new PointClass(11, 24);  // set point2 as argument with x and y

        System.out.println("Point1: " + point1);  //display point1 from toString method
        System.out.println("Point2: " + point2); //display point2 from toString method
        System.out.println();

        point1.setPointX(35);

        System.out.println("Point1: " + point1);  
        System.out.println("Point2: " + point2); 
        System.out.println();

        point2.setPointY(13);

        System.out.println("Point1: " + point1);  
        System.out.println("Point2: " + point2);
    }

}
```

When I just ran this I got this output

```
Lab1 Point
January 17, 2014

Point1: x = 0 y = 0
Point2: x = 11 y = 24

Point1: x = 35 y = 0
Point2: x = 11 y = 24

Point1: x = 35 y = 0
Point2: x = 11 y = 13
```

Comment: And more important thing he is importing `java.awt.Point`

Comment: Still getting an error when trying to use point2.setPointY. 
The method pointX(int) is undefined for the type PointTest

Comment: Thats because you arent using your pointclass, your point2 is java.awt.point. try making a constructor in your pointclass and using it instead.

Comment: Okay, took out the java.awt.point and now getting these two errors, 
The constructor Point(int, int) is undefined for `Point point2 = new Point(11,24);` 

The method setPointX(int) is undefined for the type PointTest for `point1 = setPointX(35);`

Comment: You need to change that to `PointClass(int, int)` since that is the name of your class, and add that constructor to that class because right now you don't have one. I will update my answer.

Comment: @csmckelvey Okay I am still getting an error, I updated the code based on what I was given.  

**PointTest.java:13: error: constructor PointClass in class PointClass cannot be applied to given types;
PointClass point1 = new PointClass(); 
                                    ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error**

Taken from command line, thing is I have to have a no arguments constructor, I don't get it..

Comment: If you are referring to the default constructor, that is only there if you don't make one of your own (which we did with PointClass(int, int)). Maybe you are thinking that `public void setPoints()` is a constructor? It's a bit late for me right now, but tomorrow I will try to write out all that I have been talking about to give you a complete example.

Comment: @user3015009 Try using what I wrote this morning. Main difference was removing your `setPoints()` and changing it to a no-args constructor.

Comment: @csmckelvey Great! Thank you, I got everything working, I think the main thing was my getters and setters and that's what was confusing me and also like you said getting rid of the `setPoints()`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @csmckelvey How do I do that?

Never mind, I got it. You might see me again through here, I'm in a advanced Java class this semester, I'm trying to work through stuff on my own but theres some stuff that I just don't get at all.

Comment: No problem! If all else fails you can email me when you post a question. It's csmckelvey@gmail.com.

Comment: Alright, thanks! If I email, my address is oinia12@hotmail.com just so you know